# Format number formula

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a number field in Crystal Report that must be shown in a specific format:

Eg:

12345678

must be shown as

1234-5678

I'm using a formula to transform the number to string, substring it 2 times and concatenate both values:

```
StringVar ordenT := Totext(GroupName ({DataTableInfCR.Orden}));
StringVar OrdenT1 := MID(ordenT,1,4);
StringVar OrdenT2 := MID(ordenT,4,4);
StringVar NroOrden := OrdenT1 +"-"+ OrdenT2;
```

However, the output for this code ends up being somthing like this:

12.3-45.6

I'm sure it because the default number format is with dots (ex: 12345678 will be 12.345.678)

How can I change the format via formula before my code??

Thanks!

Comment: Is the number always the same length and is the dash always in the same spot (after the 4th digit)? And if you have a decimal, do you just want the whole number and forget about the decimal? What about rounding up?

Comment: The field is static, that means, it's always gonna be 8-digit numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, to remove the decimals you use

```
StringVar ordenT := Totext(GroupName ({DataTableInfCR.Orden}),0);
```

or

```
StringVar ordenT := cStr(GroupName ({DataTableInfCR.Orden}),0);
```

EDIT:

See if this will take care of it all:

```
totext(GroupName({DataTableInfCR.Orden}),0,""),"xxxx-xxxx")
```

Comment: That last part did it. Thanks!